# How to run composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

I'am executing this in my windows console:

```
php composer.json create-project test2
```

I just get the above string and nothing happens? how to properly run the composer.json to create a project?

Comment: here's composer installation guide, also 'getting started' should explain how things work, https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: ... nobody say other detail... use `composer update` in the same folder that have `composer.json`,  when the composer command (eg. test with `% composer --version`) already exists in your terminal.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You must download composer:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

or

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

and next you should run if you have composer.json file:

```
composer.phar install
```

or if you want create new project

```
composer.phar create-project
```

Comment: Do I have to do curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php on the directory of the composer.json or anywhere?

Comment: You can do it in any directory. I always download it to /opt/composer directory and add /opt/composer to $PATH

Comment: use `composer update` in the same folder that have `composer.json`,  when the composer command (eg. test with `% composer --version`) already exists in your terminal.

Answer (score 21):

use `composer update` in the same folder that has `composer.json`, when the composer command (eg. test with `composer --version`) already exists in your terminal.

Answer (score 15):

i used 'composer install' and it's working good

```
composer install
```

or

```
php composer install
```

Answer (score -4):

The answer is don't make it so difficult. Why do I need composer, just let me download the files and upload them to my server. Otherwise, I must first study to get a degree in composer rocket science. My time isn't valuable so I like to waste it trying to figure stuff out instead of doing the work for my client.

Comment: I think I do not get your point. It is hard to see how this is a helpful answer. Actually to me it seems borderline not an answer at all. If there is a helpful solution in there you will have to [edit] to make it more obvious.

Comment: This answer shows more insight and common sense than half the answers on stackoverflow.